# Using typeahead with mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, typeahead

I have used a piece of code that implements twitter autocomplete typeahead with static data source. The link I've taken the code from is:
[Jquery Typeahead search](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/)

The code is working fine for me with static data. But I want to implement the same using mysql database as a source for the data. I have the php file ready that takes the query as GET request and returns a json encoded array. The thing is, the css of this link works perfectly for me, so I want to use the same styling for dynamic data source as well.
Can someone please tell me a way out to incorporate dynamic data source in typeahead?
Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you consider "dynamic". If you want to have the database put out the list in which the jQuery script should search, you might want to try the example from "country v2". If you want to the jQuery script to query your server as you type, you should have a look at "User v1".

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). This can also be [handled with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), which you are already using.

Comment: I agree. But typeahead with jquery is lightweight and concise, so I want to go on with it.